# roll over camera!

Tags: unity

I'm making a prototype. I used the Unity RollerBall, prefab, but I need to be able to attach a camera to it and keep it steady. I need to have it follow the ball as it rolls, but have the camera roll with it. Any ideas?

Comment: Use ball's position only, not rotation. And Use Transform.LookAt, Vector3.Lerp to camera positioning.

Comment: This is explained in one of the basic Unity video tutorials. ["Project Roll-a-Ball Chapter 4: Moving the Camera"](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-camera)

Comment: By "have the camera roll with it", do you mean as if the camera were attached to the ball by a long pole, rotating along with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work with the basic Transform methods.
At first you need the target position to know from where to start the calculation.
Then you substract the direction vector to receive a new position for the camera.
To set the camera view to the target transform use `transform.LookAt`.

```
public Transform targetTransform;
public float distanceToTarget;

void Update ()
{
    transform.position = targetTransform.position -
        (Vector3.forward * distanceToTarget);

    transform.LookAt(targetTransform);
}
```

Attach this script to the camera. To set the perspective of the viewer to the target transform you need to tweak the `Vector3.forward` value.